# print key values not working as expected with JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to print out all the key values in the JSON below but for whatever reason its only printing the first set array of values for me.

How can i make it that all the key values in the idValue String are printed out?

Edit: I'm now getting the error:

Unexpected Error : JSONObject["submenu"] not a string.

Code

```
import com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Map;

public class testing {
    static Multimap<String, String> allMappedKeyValues = LinkedListMultimap.create();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String idValue = "[{\"link\": \"/us_new/en/home\",\"amid\": \"1__home\",\"title\": \"Home\"}, {\"link\": \"/us_new/en/home/diagnosis\",\"amid\": \"2__diagnosis\",\"title\": \"Diagnosis\"}, {\"link\": \"/us_new/en/home/loss\",\"amid\": \"3__loss\",\"title\": \"loss\",\"submenu\": [{\"amid\": \"4__quiz\",\"name\": \"quiz\",\"title\": \"quiz\"},{\"amid\": \"5__questions\",\"name\": \"questions\",\"title\": \"Questions\"}]}]";

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(idValue);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray keys = object.names();

            for (int j = 0; j < keys.length(); ++j)
            {
                String key = keys.getString(j);
                Object value = object.get(key);

                if (value instanceof JSONArray) {

                    JSONArray array1 = (JSONArray) value;

                    for (int k = 0; k < array1.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject object1 = array1.getJSONObject(k);

                        JSONArray keys1 = object1.names();

                        String key2 = keys1.getString(k);
                        String value2 = object1.getString(key2);
                        String title2 = object1.getString("title");
//                        System.out.println("-key :" + key2 + "\n-value " + value2 + "\n-title :" + title2);

                        if (key2.contains("amid")) {
                            allMappedKeyValues.put(value2 + "__title", title2);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    String key1 = keys.getString(j);
                    String value1 = object.getString(key1);
                    String title1 = object.getString("title");
//                    System.out.println("-key :" + key1 + "\n-value " + value1 + "\n-title :" + title1);

                    if (key.equals("amid")) {
                        allMappedKeyValues.put(value1 + "__title", title1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : allMappedKeyValues.entries()) {
            System.out.println("This is the key-" + entry.getKey() + " value-" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

JSON

```
[{"link": "/us_new/en/home","amid": "1__home","title": "Home"}, {"link": "/us_new/en/home/diagnosis","amid": "2__diagnosis","title": "Diagnosis"}, {"link": "/us_new/en/home/loss","amid": "3__loss","title": "loss","submenu": [{"amid": "4__quiz","name": "quiz","title": "quiz"},{"amid": "5__questions","name": "questions","title": "Questions"}]}]
```

Output

```
  Entered loop :0
-key :link
-value /us_new/en/home
-title :Home
Entered loop :1
-key :amid
-value 1__home
-title :Home
Entered loop :2
-key :title
-value Home
-title :Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following recursive function "parseJsonArray" to parse your nested jsonArrays.

```
String idValue = "[{\"link\": \"/us_new/en/home\",\"amid\": \"1__home\",\"title\": \"Home\"}, {\"link\": \"/us_new/en/home/diagnosis\",\"amid\": \"2__diagnosis\",\"title\": \"Diagnosis\"}, {\"link\": \"/us_new/en/home/loss\",\"amid\": \"3__loss\",\"title\": \"loss\",\"submenu\": [{\"amid\": \"4__quiz\",\"name\": \"quiz\",\"title\": \"quiz\"},{\"amid\": \"5__questions\",\"name\": \"questions\",\"title\": \"Questions\"}]}]";

parseJsonArray(idValue);

private void parseJsonArray(String jsonString) throws JSONException {
    System.out.println("jsonString: " + jsonString);

    JSONArray objects = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    JSONArray  nestedJsonArray;
    JSONObject  nestedJsonObject;

    for(int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = objects.getJSONObject(i);
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();                
            Object nestedObject = jsonObject.get(key);
            if (nestedObject instanceof JSONArray) {
                System.out.println("it's an array: " + key);
                nestedJsonArray = (JSONArray)nestedObject;
                parseJsonArray(nestedJsonArray.toString());
            }
            else if (nestedObject instanceof JSONObject) {
                nestedJsonObject = (JSONObject)nestedObject;
                System.out.printf("key : %s | value : %s | title : %s\n", key, nestedJsonObject.getString(key), nestedJsonObject.getString("title"));
            }
            else {
                System.out.printf("key : %s | value : %s | title : %s\n", key, jsonObject.getString(key), jsonObject.getString("title"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace `[]`, your JSON is in correct format. You can actually create `JSONArray` directly from the String,

```
String idValue = "[{\"link\":\"/us_new/en/home\",\"amid\":\"1__home\",\"title\":\"Home\"},{\"link\":\"/us_new/en/home/diagnosis\",\"amid\":\"2__diagnosis\",\"title\":\"Diagnosis\"},{\"link\":\"/us_new/en/home/treatment\",\"amid\":\"3__loss\",\"title\":\"loss\"}]";
JSONArray objects = new JSONArray(idValue);
for(int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = objects.getJSONObject(i);

    Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        System.out.printf("key : %s | value : %s\n", key, jsonObject.get(key));
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
key : link | value : /us_new/en/home
key : amid | value : 1__home
key : title | value : Home
key : link | value : /us_new/en/home/diagnosis
key : amid | value : 2__diagnosis
key : title | value : Diagnosis
key : link | value : /us_new/en/home/treatment
key : amid | value : 3__loss
key : title | value : loss
```

Comment: Hey, I'm now getting the error submenu is not a String. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You only read the first JSON object (`{\"link\":\"/us_new/en/home\",\"amid\":\"1__home\",\"title\":\"Home\"}`). In order to read all 3 objects, first change the JSON String to an array (add the missing `[` and `]`):

```
String idValue = "[{\"link\":\"/us_new/en/home\",\"amid\":\"1__home\",\"title\":\"Home\"},{\"link\":\"/us_new/en/home/diagnosis\",\"amid\":\"2__diagnosis\",\"title\":\"Diagnosis\"},{\"link\":\"/us_new/en/home/treatment\",\"amid\":\"3__loss\",\"title\":\"loss\"}]";
```

Then iterate over the array:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(idValue);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length (); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject (i);
    JSONArray keys = object.names();
    for (int j = 0; j < keys.length(); ++j) {
        System.out.println("Entered loop :"+j);
        String key = keys.getString(j);
        String value = object.getString(key);
        String title = object.getString("title");
        System.out.println("-key :" + key + "\n-value " + value + "\n-title :" + title);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Entered loop :0
-key :link
-value /us_new/en/home
-title :Home
Entered loop :1
-key :amid
-value 1__home
-title :Home
Entered loop :2
-key :title
-value Home
-title :Home
Entered loop :0
-key :link
-value /us_new/en/home/diagnosis
-title :Diagnosis
Entered loop :1
-key :amid
-value 2__diagnosis
-title :Diagnosis
Entered loop :2
-key :title
-value Diagnosis
-title :Diagnosis
Entered loop :0
-key :link
-value /us_new/en/home/treatment
-title :loss
Entered loop :1
-key :amid
-value 3__loss
-title :loss
Entered loop :2
-key :title
-value loss
-title :loss
```

Comment: Hey, I'm now getting the error submenu is not a String. I have updated my question

Comment: @KahunaDub I tried your modified JSON String with my answer's code and didn't get an error. It printed `-key :submenu
-value [{"name":"quiz","amid":"4__quiz","title":"quiz"},{"name":"questions","amid":"5__questions","title":"Questions"}]`

Comment: i need to get those key values inside the submenu as well. The code im using is quite long so I cant put it all up here only snippets. How would it get those key values as well?

Comment: @KahunaDub you can change `String value = object.getString(key);` to `Object value = object.get(key);`. Then you can check `if (value instanceof JSONArray)`, cast it to `JSONArray` and iterate over that array if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm still getting that error though. I have updated my code. Its not producing the full list of key values either now?

Comment: @KahunaDub It should be `JSONArray array1 = (JSONArray) value;` and eliminate `value1`.

Comment: thanks for all your help. It's still the same though. I've update the code with your latest suggestion

Comment: I've managed to get all but one of the key/value pairs printing. The 4th Key value is missing. Any ideas whats up? If you update your answer ill accept it. I've updated my code as well